# Infinix Android showing error - Cannot load Android System. Your data may be corrupt

Tags: android, reset, recovery, data-recovery

I have an issue with my Android Mobile - Infinix.
On Restart It's just showing below error on screen to 'Reset Factory Data' option as below:

[image]

As we know by doing or performing 'Factory Data Reset', It will erase all the mobile data but,
I don't want to loose my mobile's storage data, What can I do now?